# Async and await tasks take too much time

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-http

I need to call all APIs and store a local database before login. I used the sqflite plugin. **can't add background running, that's why I used await**.

*1st running storeRegister() after process completed then running storeEquipmentReg likewise.*

**button onPressed():**

```
await HelperDatabase1().storeRegister(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeEquipmentReg(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeGetUserPreference(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeDefRegisterCat(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeDefCatMaster(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeDefCatRelation(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeWoDescription(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeAssetAssembly(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeCategoryDefect(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeWorkSource(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeWorkTypes(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storePriorities(_url, tokens);
await HelperDatabase1().storeSignIn(1);
await HelperSync().insert(_url, tokens);
await Helper().insert(token);
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/listView', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

example storeCategoryDefect method:(All other code same)

```
   storeCategoryDefect(String url, String token) async {
    var db = await db1;
    Batch batch = db.batch();
    final response = await http.get(
      '$url/nativeapi/v1.0/CategoryDefect',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    CategoryDefect model = CategoryDefect.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    int length = model.data.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var data = DataCategoryDefect(
        i: model.data[i].i,
        d: model.data[i].d,
      );
      batch.insert(
        'CategoryDefectTable',
        data.toMap(),
      );
    }
    await batch.commit();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to execute them in a specific order, you can execute them simultaneously like:

```
await Future.wait([
  HelperDatabase1().storeRegister(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeEquipmentReg(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeGetUserPreference(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeDefRegisterCat(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeDefCatMaster(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeDefCatRelation(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeWoDescription(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeAssetAssembly(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeCategoryDefect(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeWorkSource(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeWorkTypes(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storePriorities(_url, tokens),
  HelperDatabase1().storeSignIn(1),
  HelperSync().insert(_url, tokens),
  Helper().insert(token),
]);
```

If you need to order them, then create `await Future.wait` batch instead like your example. For example, first priorities inside the first Future.wait, seconds are after first Future.wait bla bla...

Comment: Ok I'll try and let you know..but Is it solution for my problem? Can future.wait fix slowness issue?

Comment: @user9139407 Of course, that's why I answered your question :)

Comment: @mathronaut, in this answer you will get it you will wait only the most expensive process time. In your code you are waiting the sum of all process times. It can be very faster or a little faster but it will be always faster.

Comment: @mathronaut thank you so much for supporting. finally, Jira ticket is updated after one month..thank you

Comment: @mathronaut Is it possible to call all APIs once and store all data on local sametime?

Comment: ```void storeAll(String url, String token) async {
  final urlList = ['$url/nativeapi/v1.0/Register','$url/nativeapi/v1.0/EquipmentReg'];
  final cacheTable = ['registerTable','EquipmentRegTable'];

  final responses = await Future.wait(
    urlList.map((String url) {
      return http.get(url,headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
    }),
  );

  final List<dynamic> caches = responses.map((response) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }).toList();
}```

Comment: @mathronaut 75% improvement than previous method. is it impossible to improvement more

Comment: @user9139407 Yes it's possible to save all data to local at the sametime with same method. The improvement you get from this method is maximum, so don't expect any superior trick to get it further.